# Automatically add fancybox class to image links

Tags: php, jquery, image, fancybox

I'm using the Pulse CMS for designing a simple static website that needs to be editable. I'm using FancyBox for image highlighting and enhancing.

What I want is for all the images to **automatically** be associated with FancyBox without having to add the code manually.

**Basically something like this**

```
<img src="image.jpg">
```

**should become**

```
<a class="fancybox" href="image.jpg"><img src="image.jpg"></a>
```

I hope it's clear what I'm aiming for. I fiddled around using jQuery and PHP, but couldn't really figure it out. I don't even know if this is possible, maybe if not there are alternatives.

**In response to JFK suggestion -- please tell what I'm doing wrong here:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>     
        <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery.fancybox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>       
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("img").on("click", function(){
                $.fancybox($(this).attr("src"),{
                    // API options
                    padding : 0 // example
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <img src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/408/287.jpg" alt=""/>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to wrap your code in the `.ready()` method ... check **[updated JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/g5uzx/3/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is `all the images to automatically be associated with FancyBox`, then maybe you don't even need to wrap - `.wrap()` - them with an anchor. A different approach would be to link them directly to fancybox on `click` like :

```
$("img").on("click", function(){
    $.fancybox($(this).attr("src"),{
        // API options
        padding : 0 // example
    });
});
```

In this way, you don't process anything until the actual image is clicked. This would be better in terms of performance (consider 100+ images being wrapped every page load)

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/g5uzx/)**

**NOTE** : `.on()` requires jQuery v1.7+

**EDIT** :

[Umair Abid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/975932/umair-abid)'s comment about specificity is worth to consider because you may not like to open in fancybox ALL your page's images (which it would include your logo.) It would be a better idea to target those images in your specific content container so this line

```
$("img").on("click", function(){
```

... would work better like

```
$("#contentContainer img").on("click", function(){
```

Comment: I'm about to go crazy. Your jsFiddle works fine of course, but it just won't work for my website. Clicking the images doesn't do anything. I'm sorry I can't give any specific feedback, but I'm stuck :/

Comment: I've added an example in my original question above for clarification.

Comment: @Daniel You need to wrap your code in the `.ready()` method ... check **[updated JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/g5uzx/3/)**

Comment: Well this was embarassing... Forgot to load the function. Works!

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's .wrap() function to wrap all of the images in the page with an anchor tag pointing to the image location

Answer (score 0):

```
$("img").wrap(function() {
    return '<a class="fancybox" href="' + $(this).attr("src") + '"/>';
});
```

This should work.

**EDIT**: whoa typos out the wazoo

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is possible through jquery. First you need to give class on img tags which you want to convert into fancybox url, than use the following jquery code

```
$('img.attach_fancybox').each(function(){
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).after('<a class="fancybox" href="'+src+'"><img src="'+src+'"></a>');
    $(this).hide();
})
```

I haven't tested the code so let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: I guess you missed the part where it says : `without having to add the code manually.`

Comment: @JFK: may be but I trying to be specific, you can still remove the class selector and select all the images but I think it will not be good solution to convert all the img tags.... no one wants to open logo in fancybox ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$("img").wrap(function() {
  return "<a class='fancybox' href='" + $(this).attr("src") + "' />";
});
```